# Changing certain letters in a string

Tags: string, recursion, scheme

Edit:

```
(define leet-helper
  (lambda (string)
    (cond
      [(null? (string->list string)) ""]
      [(equal? (car string)#\e)
       (cons 3 (leet-speak (cdr string)))]
      [(equal?  (car string) #\s)
       (cons 5 (leet-speak (cdr string)))]
      [(equal? (car string) #\o)
       (cons 0 (leet-speak (cdr string)))]
      [else string])))

(define leet-speak
  (lambda (string)
    (list->string (string->list (leet-speak string)))))
```

I'm working on a problem that takes a string and returns the same string with all e's turned into 3's, all s's turned into 5's, and all o's turned into 0's. I posted what I have created so far, but I keep getting errors when I try to test this so I know I'm not doing something right. Also.. this code has 3 *separate* conditionals, but if the string given is "eso", I want all 3 characters to be changed, not just the 'e'. I'm not sure how to do that, or if my recursion will take care of that by itself [?]. Any pointers would be appreciated!

```
(define leet-speak
  (lambda (string)
    (cond
      [(null? (string->list string)) ""]
      [(equal? (car (string->list string)) 'e) 
       (list->string (cons 3 (leet-speak (cdr (string->list string)))))]
      [(equal? (string->list (car string)) 's)
       (list->string (cons 5 (leet-speak (cdr (string->list string)))))]
      [(equal? (string->list (car string)) 'o)
       (list->string (cons 0 (leet-speak (cdr (string->list string)))))])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now suppose that we test your program (by stepping manually) with a string "test". The first error we see is that you have no `else` case. Second, you will notice that when you compare `(car (string->list string))` with `'e` you will always get false because when a string is decomposed it is decomposed as characters (`#\e`) and not symbols.

I would suggest that when you test your code, take note of the errors that you keep getting (what kind of errors? you don't mention them in your question; scheme is usually pretty informative with its error messages) and try to fix each of them. For instance, if you get

```
string->list : expects argument of type <string>; given myinput
```

then you know that there is something wrong with the type of `myinput` that you are giving `string->list`. This type of errors occurs a few time in your code. One way that I like to use when I have problems with recursion input types is to use helper functions/wrapper function (*hint*).

Moreover, a good way to test recursive programs is to run through them manually (e.g. with a string "test", as mentioned in the beginning) and then see where you get stuck and fix the program accordingly.

I hope that this will help set you in the right direction, and let me know if you need more pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. In the code above I kept getting the error "except in car, __ is not a pair," which I don't really understand because the list containing those characters can be broken down into car and cdr. I have made some corrections and now my code crashes my laptop :P The main thing I'm not understanding is how I can check for all 3 characters at the same time.

Comment: For the 3 characters, think about it this way: you are going through a list, and for each item of the list you want to check if it's 'good' or 'not good' (e, s, o, which you then replace), until you reach the end of the list. So what you want to do is suppose you have a list (cons s (cons e (cons a empty))) you check s, change it to 5, keep the 5, check e, change it to 3, keep the 5 and 3, check the a, it stays a, keep 5, 3, a, check empty, finish, so that you now have (cons 5 (cons 3 (cons a empty))). It really should not matter how many times the characters appear or how long your list is.

Comment: As for the error, this is because you have a syntax error 
(equal? (string->list (car string)) 's)
should be 
(equal? (car (string->list string)) 's) 
- and the same for the third case, the first case is ok - 
since car takes a list as a argument.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your edit. The car error is still because you gave a string as an argument instead of a list. Hint: your leet-speak function takes in a string, but you want to recurse with a list. So leet-helper should take a list and return a list and leet-speak takes a string and returns a string. I think this is the most I can help without giving away the answer (since it's a homwework) :P Good luck!

Comment: Ahh okay I see where my problem was. Thanks.